# overloading an operator that has already been defined

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust, nvcc

I want to overload operator * but I keep getting function "operator*(int, int)" has already been defined. I'm using Thrust library and want to use my own * in my kernel.

```
 __device__ int operator*(int x, int y)
{
    int value = ...                                    
    return value;                                     
}
```

Comment: What is the compiler ?

Comment: @IlDivinCodino  I'm using NVCC

Comment: How would you do this in pure C++?  Can you give an example?  Doesn't operator overloading [require a class definition of some sort](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/intrinsic-types#intrinsics-and-operator-overloading)?  Either the operator overload has to be a class member function, or the operator overload has to take a class as one of its arguments?

Comment: As @RobertCrovella noted, you are not allowed to overload any operator for the built-in types. See Section 3.6 [over.built] for details.

Comment: @RobertCrovella yes that's right. So there's no way to do that? What I want to do is to use Thrust's reduction with my own * operator.

Comment: thrust::reduce already offers you [the opportunity to specify your own binary operator](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__reductions.html#ga5e9cef4919927834bec50fc4829f6e6b) to be used in the reduction.  Wrap your operator in a functor and pass it to thrust::reduce.  The [quick start guide](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) gives an example of defining a unary operator in a functor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I want to do is to use Thrust's reduction with my own * operator

`thrust::reduce` offers you an opportunity to [use your own binary operator](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__reductions.html#ga5e9cef4919927834bec50fc4829f6e6b) in the reduction.  The operator should be provided via a C++ functor.

Here's a worked example showing the use of a binary operator to find the maximum value in a set of numbers:

```
$ cat t1093.cu
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <iostream>

const int dsize = 10;

struct max_op
{
template <typename T>
  __host__ __device__
  T operator()(const T &lhs, const T &rhs) const
  {
    return (lhs>rhs)?lhs:rhs;
  }
};

int main(){

   thrust::device_vector<int> data(dsize, 1);
   data[2] = 10;
   int result = thrust::reduce(data.begin(), data.end(), 0, max_op());
   std::cout << "max value: " << result << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t1093 t1093.cu
$ ./t1093
max value: 10
$
```

Comment: Great thanks. Can I do the same thing for CUB? I tried to define my own operator for scan in cub the same way but didn't work.

Comment: You can do something similar in CUB for some algorithm implementations.  Example code for passing a minimum operator (very similar to above max operator) to `cub::DeviceReduce::Reduce` is provided in [the cub documentation](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_reduce.html#aa4adabeb841b852a7a5ecf4f99a2daeb).   It can also be done for `cub::DeviceScan::InclusiveScan` and example code is provided [here](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_scan.html#af27a73a9a8daef1b4fe5a16233932e30).

Comment: I tried CUB example for custom operator and it works, but the problem is it's just working for a block size arrays;. That is less than 1024 elements. I'm using DeviceScan but yet it always hangs for larger inputs.

Comment: Probably you should create a new question here on SO, describing what you did and what the problem was.  Be sure to include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (i.e. a complete code that someone else could compile and run and see the issue) because SO [expects that](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for questions of the form "why isn't this code working?"